# DD-WRT: DNSMasq expand-hosts not working

Tags: dns, dhcp, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I have a Linksys router running DD-WRT (Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (09/08/09) mini). I have it successfully resolving the DNS names for my DHCP-assigned systems, but only when I fully-qualify those domains. This is despite using the "expand-hosts" DNSMasq additional option, which is supposed to activate this precise function.

Here's my dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=br0
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.dnsmasq
domain=example.com
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dnsmasq.leases
dhcp-lease-max=51
dhcp-option=lan,3,10.77.0.5
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=lan,10.77.0.100,10.77.0.149,255.255.0.0,1440m
dhcp-host=00:1A:A0:1D:82:5A,astatichostname,10.77.1.40,infinite
expand-hosts
```

(FYI: example.com and astatichostname are placeholders for the real-deal names I use. My network uses 10.77.0.0/16; my router is on 10.77.0.5.)

Results:

```
> nslookup astatichostname 10.77.0.5
Server:     10.77.0.5
Address:    10.77.0.5#53

** server can't find astatichostname: NXDOMAIN

> nslookup astatichostname.example.com 10.77.0.5
Server:     10.77.0.5
Address:    10.77.0.5#53

Name:   astatichostname.example.com
Address: 10.77.1.40
```

Is there something else that could be tripping up expand-host in DNSMasq?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is old, but it's one of the top google results for the issue, and I finally figured it out.

The problem is that's not what `expand-hosts` does. The documentation on it is very fuzzy, but what `expand-hosts` does is adds the domain to host entries in `/etc/hosts`, not to dns queries. So for example

**/etc/hosts:**

```
10.77.0.5 astatichostname
```

**dnsmasq.conf:**

```
expand-hosts
domain=example.com
```

Then dns queries for `astatichostname.example.com` will resolve to `10.77.0.5` (in addition to DNS queries for just `astatichostname`).

---

### Solution:

So, the solution is to get dd-wrt to create the entries in `/etc/hosts` without the domain on them, and then tell dnsmasq to consider those host entries as part of the `example.com` domain when a fully qualified A record DNS query comes in.
To do this you have to:

1. Put the `example.com` domain in the **Domain Name** field on the **Setup** -> **Basic Setup** page under **Optional Settings**.
2. Blank the **LAN Domain** setting on the **Services** page under **DHCP Server**.
3. Add `expand-hosts` to **Additional DNSMasq Options** on the **Services** page under **DNSMasq**

*Step **#1** controls the `domain=` setting that gets put in the `dnsmasq.conf` file. Step **#2** removes the domain from the entries that get put in `/etc/hosts`. Step **#3** tacks the domain onto the entries in `/etc/hosts` when a fully qualified DNS query comes in.*

I'm so glad dd-wrt made this nice and simple...

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me on my DD-WRT:

```
expand-hosts
local=/lan/
domain=lan
```

I think it's because you're missing the `local` setting. I also have `lan` set as my "LAN Domain" in the GUI.

Comment: `local=/lan/` says that queries in `lan` domain are answered from /etc/hosts or DHCP only. So, if your query `xyz.lan` is not present in /etc/hosts or DHCP, it won't be forwarded to upstream DNS server.